# What is the order of executing @ModelAttribute and @InitBinder in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

if i have code like this:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){

}
@ModelAttribute
protected User initModel(){

}
```

which one will be executed first?

spring documentation said that `@InitBinder` annotated method can accept any argument `@RequestMapping` annotated method can have except command object, does that mean it accept `@ModelAttribute` argument?  can i have a code like this:

```
@ModelAttribute
protected User initModel(){

}
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, @ModelAttribute User user){

}
```

where a generated model attribute injected in `initBinder` method?

Thanks

Comment: No you cannot as, if you read the same documentation, the `@ModelAttribute` is a model object, which is potentially the command object..

Comment: thanks, so what is the order? '@initBinder' methods then '@ModelAttribute' methods? can you please point to the part in the spring reference (if any)? thanks.

Comment: @Joseph It is not not much clear, but ideally `@InitBinder` should be called first, why don't you put some `loggers/syso statement` and see which is called first.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ModelAttribute
void init() {
    LOGGER.error("init @ModelAttribute");
}

@InitBinder
void initBinder() {
    LOGGER.error("init @InitBinder");
}
```

Output
12:48:06.357 [main] ERROR rest.controller.TestController - init @InitBinder

12:48:07.341 [main] ERROR rest.controller.TestController - init @ModelAttribute

12:48:07.388 [main] ERROR codixrest.controller.TestController - init @InitBinder